# For loop - dynamically loop through more than array

Tags: javascript, createjs

I'm trying to add several sprites and their associated label to a create js container object using a for loop.

Is it possible to add both at the same time, like so?

```
NPCs.push(spriteBMP, spriteBMP2, spriteBMP3);
Lables.push(spriteLabel, spriteLabel2, spriteLabel3);
```

Loop:

```
for (npc in NPCs && label in Labels) {
    spriteContainer.addChild(npc, label);
}
```

If not, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Using Math.max to make sure we can get through all  of them
for ( var i = 0, l = Math.max(NPCs.length, Labels.length); i < l; ++i ) {
    spriteContainer.addChild(NPCs[i], Labels[i]);
}
```

Anything that is not in one of the arrays will be sent as `undefined`.